# How to post a array of complex objects (that has a array of complex objects) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I want to post some Products that has a ID and some Categories with jQuery. But I get a error in: Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelBinder.BindProperty (NullReferenceException), when I add the Categories.

Should not the default ModelBinder be able to bind this (without a ActionFilter or custom ModelBinder)?

I tried to apply a ActionFilter (to deserialize) that I found in another SO thread, but it never runs. I have also tried with jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;, jQuery 1.3.2 and 1.4.2. And in the other examples I have found, they are just posting ID, Name, etc, not another array of complex objects.

Any ideas?

Classes

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Category[] Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="Product[0]_ID" name="Product[0].ID" type="hidden" value="9" />
<input id="Product[0]_Categories[0]_ID" name="Product[0].Categories[0].ID" type="hidden" value="99" />
<input id="Product[1]_ID" name="Product[1].ID" type="hidden" value="8" />
<input id="Product[1]_Categories[0]_ID" name="Product[1].Categories[0].ID" type="hidden" value="88" />
```

Controller

```
[JsonFilter(Parameter = "p")]
public JsonResult GetProductPrice([Bind(Prefix = "Product")] Product[] p)
{
    // TODO: Implement some checking...
    return Json(true);
}
```

jQuery

```
$.post(getProductPriceUrl, $("form").serializeArray(), function(data) {
    $("#Price").html(data);
});
```

JsonFilter

```
public class JsonFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    //public Type JsonDataType { get; set; }

    private JavaScriptSerializer serializer;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Equals("application/json"))
        {
            string inputContent;

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
            {
                inputContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var result = serializer.Deserialize<Product>(inputContent);
            filterContext.ActionParameters[Parameter] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

POST #1

```
__RequestVerificationToken=sz%2BLKCzTmdGMrH3TdOYipS5z%2BJ3uVyzBtJRZrruJoUohoGaH2O3DU5%2FcuU6hX1E%2F&Product%5B0%5D.ID=9&Product%5B0%5D.Categories%5B0%5D.ID=99&Product%5B1%5D.ID=8&Product%5B1%5D.Categories%5B0%5D.ID=88
```

POST #2

```
__RequestVerificationToken=sz+LKCzTmdGMrH3TdOYipWTERHSdtCvGUhuw/dGIkgSL3rjcSLO7RJJN/rcssVwv&Product[0].ID=9&Product[0].Categories[0].ID=99&Product[1].ID=8&Product[1].Categories[0].ID=88
```

POST #3

```
[{"name":"__RequestVerificationToken","value":"sz+LKCzTmdGMrH3TdOYipcqr8WKC2eL7CRS5BZUtwzD60WkqfnjdeAcO3DQg5ss6"},{"name":"Product[0].ID","value":"9"},{"name":"Product[0].Categories[0].ID","value":"99"},{"name":"Product[1].ID","value":"8"},{"name":"Product[1].Categories[0].ID","value":"88"}]
```

Comment: You should not need an ActionFilter. Can you show the `POST` data?

Comment: Er, posts 1 & 2 are regular key/values, "post" 3 is JSON. Which do you intend, and why do it two ways? Generally, prefer standard POSTs in MVC, as JSON requires special handling.

Comment: I want to use a standard POST, but after a couple of hours of testing that and not getting it to work. I began to doubt it was possible so I tried with JSON and the "JsonFilter" after reading some SO thread with that solution.

Comment: A standard post is *far* easier than posting JSON, because MVC supports the former "out of the box", whereas JSON post support is something you have to add yourself.

Comment: Okey, do you have any idea of why I am getting a error when using standard POST then? I can not understand why the simple Product/Category example is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of to accomplish the goal of sending a complex object graph back to a the server properly wired up. One is the way you're attempting originally, that is to express the relationship in html. The other is to pass to partial views the child objects.

So you would create a partial view for a list of Categories and pass the Product.categories to it. That should take care of wiring it up properly for you.

It would be

```
@Html.Partial("_myCategoriesPartialView", Model.Categories)
```

That view of course would iterate over the collection.
I believe if you want to do it the other way with html it would look like.

```
<input id="Product[0]_ID" name="Product[0].ID" type="hidden" value="9" />
```

should be

```
<input id="Product[0].ID" name="Product[0].ID" type="hidden" value="9" />,
```

but the way to tell for sure is to look at the Response.Form data